# How to create custom hook useHistory in react v4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

I am using router v4 in my app and I can`t upgrade to v5.

I would like to use hook `useHistory` (https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/modules/hooks.js) from v5.

So.. I decide to write by myself.

My code is:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

const useHistory = (props: any) => {
  const { history: routerHistory } = props; 
  const [history, setHistory] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    setHistory(routerHistory);
  }, [routerHistory]);

  return history;
};

export default withRouter(useHistory);
```

and in second component:

```
const {history} = useHistory();
history.push(...)
```

But, seems to be wrong, any suggestions?

**jsfiddle**
https://jsfiddle.net/4gqkbxmw/

Comment: Wrong how? Could you share your log?

Comment: @Onilol hi, jsfiddle is included in post